# eval fails in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, list-comprehension

Consider the following hypothetical code:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2

    def foo(self):
        out1 = [eval('self.b')]    # ok
        print(out1)                # prints: [2]
        out2 = [eval(cmd) for cmd in ['self.b']]    # fails
        print(out2)    # NameError: name 'self' is not defined

b = B()
b.foo()
```

Why is the statement for `out1` ok, but not for `out2`, which gives the error "'self' is not defined"?

I am learning Python, and I came about this problem whilst experimenting about `eval`. Yes, I know the use of `eval` in this example is inappropriate, but just for the sake of taking this example at face value, can someone explain why the statement for `out2` gives out the error message? It seems both statements should work and give the same result.

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Because you defined a new scope without a self using list comprehension?

Comment: Note that your code would work in Python 2 because back then LC didn't introduce new scope.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using list comprehension, you actually **define a new scope**. Indeed if we alter the list comprehension to:

```
out2 = [print(globals()) or print(locals()) or eval(cmd) for cmd in ['self.b']]
```

we force Python to print the local and global variables before making the `eval(..)` call, and we obtain something like:

```
{'__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, 'b': <__main__.B object at 0x7f406f55d4a8>, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, 'B': <class '__main__.B'>, '__spec__': None}
{'.0': <list_iterator object at 0x7f406f55df28>, 'cmd': 'self.b'}
```

So as local variables we only have a `.0` and a `cmd`.

You can however pass `self` to the list comprehension by using:

```
globs = globals()
locs = locals()
out2 = [eval(cmd,globs,locs) for cmd in ['self.b']]
```

So now `eval(..)` will **use the local and global variables as defined in the scope of the function**. Since we use `locs` and `globs`. Python will pass references to these dictionaries to the `eval(..)` call.

Finally a warning as with every use of `eval(..)`: eval is a dangerous function. You better use it only if you really need it.

An additional side effect of this additional scope (introduced in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)) is that the *loop variable* does *not* leak: after the list comprehension `cmd` is cleaned up: you can no longer access it (usually it would hold the last element it has handled). For example:

```
>>> [x for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I have read about list comprehensions having their own scope, but I didn't make the connection until now.