# python oneliner for loop: namespace forgotten

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with the namespaces defined in the nested functions. Consider the following code:

```py
def fun1():
    CHARS = ['C','H','A','R','S']
    
    def fun2():
        C = 1
        H = 2
        A = 3
        R = 4
        S = 5

        # just for warp-up, to ensure oneliners indeed work
        a_list = [c for c in CHARS]
        
        # the following structure works: makes [1,2,3,4,5]
        eval_list = []
        for c in CHARS:
            eval_list.append(eval(c))
        
        # this doesn't work. why?
        oneliner_eval_list = [eval(c) for c in CHARS] # NameError: name 'C' is not defined
    
        print('func2 ran without problem')

    fun2()
    
    print('func1 ran without problem')
fun1()
```

When I run this the oneliner for loop cannot find the `CHARS` in the local namespace and thus goes one level up and finds `CHARS` in the enclosed namespace (of `fun1`). As it does so, however, it *forgets* its own namespace and cannot find `C`.

- Why is that?
- Why the multi-line for loop doesn't have such a problem?

I use Python3.

Comment: Better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194934/eval-fails-in-list-comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the list comp sets up it's own local scope when it runs. So if you have something like.

```
END = 1
def func():
    x = 0
    lst = [locals() for i in range(END)]
    print(lst)

func()
```

You get

```
[{'.0': <range_iterator object at 0x000001ACC5BF79D0>, 'i': 0}]
```

When you call `eval` without supplying a value to use as the locals it will use the locals in the current scope

```
eval(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)
```

Which in this case does not have your `C,H,A,R,S`
So you can solve it by doing.

```
def fun1():
    CHARS = ['C','H','A','R','S']
    
    def fun2():
        C = 1
        H = 2
        A = 3
        R = 4
        S = 5

        local_vars = locals()
        global_vars = globals()

        # just for warp-up, to ensure oneliners indeed work
        a_list = [c for c in CHARS]
        
        # the following structure works: makes [1,2,3,4,5]
        eval_list = []
        for c in CHARS:
            eval_list.append(eval(c))
        
        # this doesn't work. why?
        oneliner_eval_list = [eval(c, global_vars, local_vars) for c in CHARS]
    
        print('func2 ran without problem')

    fun2()
    
    print('func1 ran without problem')
fun1()
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to make them as global variables. please find the updated code here,

```
def fun1():
    CHARS = ['C', 'H', 'A', 'R', 'S']

    def fun2():
        global C, H, A,R,S # here is the update 
        C = 1
        H = 2
        A = 3
        R = 4
        S = 5

        # just for warp-up, to ensure oneliners indeed work
        a_list = [c for c in CHARS]

        # the following structure works: makes [1,2,3,4,5]
        eval_list = []
        for c in CHARS:
            eval_list.append(eval(c))

        # this doesn't work. why?
        oneliner_eval_list = [eval(c) for c in CHARS]  # NameError: name 'C' is not defined

        print('func2 ran without problem')

    fun2()

    print('func1 ran without problem')


fun1()
```

This will print

```
func2 ran without problem
func1 ran without problem
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you please also elaborate on why the other one works without a global declaration?